# Multiple conditions in IF statement (integer results only)

Tags: matlab, if-statement, integer, multiple-conditions

How to make the if statement identify only integer results of an equation

eg:

```
For n=1:240
 a=a+1
 b=a/20

 %try number 1
 If b==1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 12;
 c=c+1 %does not work
 End

 %try number 2
 If b==isinteger(b);
 c=c+1 %does not work
 End

 %try number 3
 d=isinteger(b);
 If d==1;
 c=c+1 %does not work
 End
End
```

I am only new in Matlab so excuse the simplicity of the question.

Comment: Please start to write valid code for the parts that you do understand: `if`, `for` and `end` are all written in lower case. And please indent all your code properly, Matlab's editor can do this automatically for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is

```
abs(b-round(b))<1e-12
```

or similar, which tests whether `b` is within `1e-12` of an integer.

If you want to test many numbers `b`, you can have a vector `b`, and then

```
b(abs(b-round(b))<1e-12)
```

should return the elements of `b` that are integers.

There is a Matlab command called `isinteger`, DO NOT use it, it is for determining what type of variable something is, you will be using doubles which are a different data type to integers. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: I am sorry I wrote `integer` when I meant `isinteger`. You are correct in that, as well as in the code. It works!

Comment: However I can not understand WHY the first option did not worked (the one with multiple ORs).

Comment: @user2993881 - In MATLAB you have to do `b==1 || b==2 || ...`  But you could do `any(b==(1:12))`

Comment: But you have to be careful because of numerical precision this could evaluate to false due to differences of order `eps`.

Comment: @David - You are right of course. I'm just explaining MATLAB syntax, issues of data type aside.